# code generated control not found in code wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I created control in WPF from C# and find that control on button click but not found

```
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            TextBox textBox = new TextBox();
            textBox.Name = "childTextBox";

            TextBoxes.Add(textBox);
            StackPanelParent.Children.Add(textBox);
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var findTextBox = (TextBox)this.FindName("childTextBox");
            //it's give null
        }
```

XAML Code

```
<StackPanel Margin="152,103,191,56">
        <Label Name="Loader" Visibility="Collapsed">Loader</Label>
        <Button Content="Click Me" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="342,199,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="Button_Click"/>-->
        <StackPanel Name="StackPanelParent">
        </StackPanel>
        <Button Click="Button_Click">Check</Button>
    </StackPanel>
```

Comment: Keep a reference to the TextBox as a field in the MainWindow class. No need to use FindName.

Answer (score 0):

When you dynamically create a component they cannot be found by `FindName` unless you register them first like this:

```
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            TextBox textBox = new TextBox();
            textBox.Name = "childTextBox";


            TextBoxes.Add(textBox);
            StackPanelParent.Children.Add(textBox);
            
            // register name
            RegisterName(textBox.Name, textBox);
        }
```